# NSMutableDictionary empty after adding items

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have the below code which I have written to go through the result of a database query and put each element into a Dictionary which is made up of arrays for each letter.
SO every result from the query that starts with the same letter should be put into its own array within the dictionary, with the letter as the key.
However at the end of the execution the dictionary is empty.

```
NSMutableDictionary *courseDict;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    courseDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    ...
    [self getCoursesFromDB];
    ...
}

- (void)getCoursesFromDB
{
    FMResultSet *s;
    s = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM course WHERE CourseType =?;", _coursetype];

    if ([db hadError]) {
        NSLog(@"DB Error %d: %@", [db lastErrorCode], [db lastErrorMessage]);
    }
    while ([s next]) {
        KCCourse *course = [KCCourse new];
        NSString *title = [s stringForColumnIndex:1];
        ...
        course.name = title;
        ...
        NSString *letter = [title substringToIndex:1];
        NSMutableArray *courseArray = [courseDict objectForKey:letter];
        [courseArray addObject:course];
        [courseDict setValue:courseArray forKey:letter];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [courseDict description]);
}
```

Comment: Change [courseDict objectForKey:letter] to [[courseDict objectForKey:letter]mutablecopy];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *courseArray = [courseDict objectForKey:letter];
```

You never actually construct this array - courseDict will just return nil here. You need to add

```
if(!courseArray)
{
   courseArray = [NSMutableArray new];
}
```